# Can't get rid of XML in "variables"

Tags: javascript, xml

This is involving Intuit's Quickbase. I am trying to use Highcharts.JS and have the data loaded via XML into the graph. The problem I am currently having is that in the variables I have two variables that do not need to be on the graph that relate to something else entirely.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
        <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>CoT</title>



                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


                <!-- JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {


                        var options = {
                                chart: {
                                        renderTo: 'container',
                                        type: 'column'
                                },
                                title: {
                                        text: 'Components Over Time'
                                },
                                xAxis: {
                                        categories: []
                                },
                                yAxis: {
                                        title: {
                                                text: 'Units'
                                        }
                                },
                                series: []
                        };

                        // Load the data from the XML file
                        $.get('https://dbname.quickbase.com/db/?apptoken=&act=API_DoQuery&query=%7B14.EX.%27_FID_9%7D&clist=7.24.25.26.27.28.29.30.31.32.33.34.35.36.37', function(xml) {

                                // Split the lines
                                var $xml = $(xml);

                                // push categories
                                $xml.find('variables').each(function(i, variables) {
                                        options.xAxis.categories.push($(variables).text());

                                });

                                // push series
                                $xml.find('record').each(function(i, record) {
                                        var seriesOptions = {
                                                name: $(record).find('methane').text(),
                                                data: [],
                                        };

                                        // push data points
                                        $(record).find('methane').each(function(i, point) {
                                                seriesOptions.data.push(
                                                        parseInt($(point).text())
                                                );
                                        });

                                        // add it to the options
                                        options.series.push(seriesOptions);
                                });
                                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                        });


                });
                </script>

        </head>
        <body>

                <!-- 3. Add the container -->
                <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


        </body>
</html>
```

The following has also been tried in the push categories to no success

```
$xml.find('variables:not(iol):not(__iol)').each(function(i, variables) {
  options.xAxis.categories.push($(variables).text());
 });
```

Both cause the graph to come back looking like ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyevP.jpg )

Edit: This is the XML output

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<qdbapi>
        <action>API_DoQuery</action>
        <errcode>0</errcode>
        <errtext>No error</errtext>
<dbinfo>
<name>RESULT</name>
<desc></desc>
</dbinfo>
<variables>
<__iol>&amp;rand=&#039;+new Date().getTime())};&quot;&gt;</__iol>
<iol>&lt;img qbu=&#039;module&#039; src=&#039;/i/clear2x2.gif&#039; onload=&quot;javascript:if(typeof QBU==&#039;undefined&#039;){QBU={};$.getScript(gReqAppDBID+&#039;?a=dbpage&amp;pagename=</iol>
</variables>
<chdbids>
</chdbids>
  <record>
    <sample_date>1386892800000</sample_date>
    <hydrogen>0.002</hydrogen>
    <helium>0.114</helium>
    <oxygen/>
    <hydrogen_sulfide/>
    <nitrogen>1.926</nitrogen>
    <co2>0.454</co2>
    <methane>82.163</methane>
    <ethane>6.353</ethane>
    <propane>4.760</propane>
    <iso_butane>0.618</iso_butane>
    <n_butane>1.819</n_butane>
    <iso_pentane>0.491</iso_pentane>
    <n_pentane>0.544</n_pentane>
    <hexanes_>0.756</hexanes_>
    <update_id>1408654196361</update_id>
  </record>
  <record>
    <sample_date>1383782400000</sample_date>
    <hydrogen>0.006</hydrogen>
    <helium>0.038</helium>
    <oxygen/>
    <hydrogen_sulfide/>
    <nitrogen>0.512</nitrogen>
    <co2>0.844</co2>
    <methane>83.178</methane>
    <ethane>8.678</ethane>
    <propane>3.631</propane>
    <iso_butane>0.493</iso_butane>
    <n_butane>1.097</n_butane>
    <iso_pentane>0.342</iso_pentane>
    <n_pentane>0.371</n_pentane>
    <hexanes_>0.810</hexanes_>
    <update_id>1408981434690</update_id>
  </record>
  <record>
    <sample_date>1369699200000</sample_date>
    <hydrogen>0.004</hydrogen>
    <helium>0.060</helium>
    <oxygen/>
    <hydrogen_sulfide/>
    <nitrogen>1.684</nitrogen>
    <co2>0.443</co2>
    <methane>77.742</methane>
    <ethane>10.430</ethane>
    <propane>6.842</propane>
    <iso_butane>0.587</iso_butane>
    <n_butane>1.482</n_butane>
    <iso_pentane>0.232</iso_pentane>
    <n_pentane>0.249</n_pentane>
    <hexanes_>0.245</hexanes_>
    <update_id>1408981112624</update_id>
  </record>
</qdbapi>
```

Comment: Is requirement to remove `variables` node ?

Comment: Well not so much the whole node, I am mainly trying to remove the <_iol> and <iol> elements from it.

Comment: Result of "empty" `variables` node ? No text from `variables` preserved ?

Comment: Well there is actually another variable (somehow my clipboard still had it before I added in the new variable "methane" that contains the value "methane" so <methane>methane</methane> is also a variable.

Comment: Requirement for elements `variables` and `methane` to be empty ? , _not_ removed ?

Comment: I need methane text to be there (as well as more later on, but for testing purposes just methane) so that it will fill in the categories to label the methane data on the chart, but I do not need the iol elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   // note the space character between tags ,
   // to prevent rendering `<variables />` within xml
   $xml.find("variables").replaceWith("<variables> </variables>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xwzox6rg/